# Jmeter wait until CSV File is readable

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan with two thread groups. One thread group is reliant on data written from the other thread group.

This design seems to work, except for a race condition that I am facing. In the dependant thread group I have added a check to see if the common file exists, before attempting to read from it.

Currently I am using the following expression in a while controller, that peforms a sleep action.

```
${__groovy(!((new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "/someFileName")).exists()))}
```

The exception I am facing is from my dependant thread group, an IllegalArgumentException when attempting to read from the file, with an error message stating file needs to exist or be readable. What I think is happening is that my check passes because the file is created but the first row doesnt exist yet.

Is there a work around for such an issue?

I have tried the following approach from a js223 pre-processor with not much luck..

```
def boolean isFileReadable() {
    try {
        File file = new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() +"/sampleData/temp/vbinformation.csv");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fileReader.read();
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
        print(false)
    }
    print(true)
    return true;
}

while (!isFileReadable()) {
    sleep(2000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Inter Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) to share the data (String) between threads as a quick solution if you want to share just a string.

If you have more than one value to be passed in a row and want to stick with your solution, you may check the following condition too.

```
file.length()>0
```

Also, you may consider using a [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) with the JSR223 element to ensure the file is accessed by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements)
2. According to [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) configuration elements are executed **before anything else**

So if you start your Thread Groups at the same time when the Thread Group with the CSV Data Set Config starts it tries to read the CSV file and fails because it's not there. So I would recommend migrating to the [__CSVRead() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) which reads the CSV file just when the function is called

Another option is using [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#introduction) for passing the data between Thread Groups, you can use either `props` shorthand in the any JSR223 Test Element or [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__P() functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) combination